# “Input line is too long” error in BAT File

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, abaqus

But my .bat file is very simple.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.inp) do (
    start abaqus job=%%a user=user.for cpus=6 int
)
```

There are only 8 .inp files. But only two commands get run, and then the error `Input line is too long` pops up.

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask].  What do you mean by "pops up"?  Is it an actual pop-up window?  If it's output in the console window, [edit] your post, copy and past output into your post.

Comment: Are you aware that by using the `start` command you are essentially trying to run multiple `abaqus` commands in parallel? How many instances of `abaqus` can be run at the same time? If of course `abaqus` is really `abaqus.bat`, you should probably replace `start` with `call`

Comment: If you run the command from a command prompt with just a single file do you get the error?